# How to move floated divs to the centre of a container

Tags: html, css

I've got two rows of boxes inside a container and I need them to be in the center of the page. I cannot set the width of the container because the stuff inside might change.

The reason why I don't break up the boxes into two rows within the HTML is because I'm using media queries to force two rows when the screen is tight, but it would naturally be one row when there is space on the screen.

Note that I have an empty div for clearfix. Feel free to remove it if you think there is a better method.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

The container is grey for illustration only, in my app it would be clear.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oc0w0n4n/)

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/93ay65ex/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the elements, then you could set the `display` of the wrapper element to `inline-block` and then add `text-align: center` to the parent element for horizontal centering:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6noqry0v/)

```
.container {
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .center-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
.box {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}
.container {
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .center-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Using flexboxes, you could also use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/unvhtwpp/)

```
.container {
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}
.container {
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed. The other answer required a set width while this one didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a container div and give it a width and margin: 0 auto;
http://jsfiddle.net/oc0w0n4n/1/

```
.center{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:140px;
}

   <div class="center">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: ..but the OP said that the width of the items might change. This wouldn't work for dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<div class="container">    
  <div align="center" style="padding-left: 532px;">    
    <div class="box">1</div>    
    <div class="box">2</div>    
    <div class="box">3</div>    
    <div class="box">4</div>    
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>    
    </div>    
</div>`
```